# OPTIONS(POST) call to API from JS not sending cookies in request header with payload

Tags: javascript, cookies, axios, fetch-api

We are using `axios` and `fetch` to make API call from VueJS(javascript). We follow the https://sabe.io/blog/javascript-pass-cookies-fetch-axios and add `withCredentials: true` in axios and `credentials: "include"` in `fetch` call.

It works fine with `GET` API call, it send `cookies` in request header and our server is able to validate that request based on cookies.

When we do `axios.post` or `fetch(..., {method: "POST", ...})` its not sending the `cookies` in the `request` headers. I tested without payload, and when same API call happens without `payload`, it send cookies.

I debug it from server side, and found that, when there is `payload` in the `fetch` or `axios.post`, it send `OPTIONS` request before sending the `POST` request. We not added any code for `OPTIONS` call in our code, but seems like when there is payload, `fetch` or `axios` send `OPTIONS` call before making `POST` call. When they make `OPTIONS` call, it wont include `cookies` even we set `credentials: "include"` in `fetch` or `{withCredentials: true}` in `axios`.

```
 01 import axios from 'axios';
 02 axios.defaults.baseURL = "https://api.test.com";
 03 export async function MyFunc() {
 04   const postData = {
 05     fetch_enabled: false,
 06   };
 07
 08   let retval;
 09   try {
 10     const axiosInstance = axios.create({ withCredentials: true });
 11     const response = await axiosInstance.post("/class/student/",
 12       postData,
 13       { headers: { "Content-type": "application/json" } }
 14     );
 15   //  const response = await fetch(axios.defaults.baseURL + "/class/student/", {
 16   //    method: "POST",
 17   //    credentials: "include",
 18   //    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
 19   //    body: JSON.stringify(postData),
 20   //  });
 21     retval = response.data;
 22   } catch (error) {
 23     retval = {"error": error};
 24   }
 25   return retval;
 26 }
```

In above code, if I comment out `12, 13` lines or `18, 19` lines in `fetch`, it send request with `cookies` in it. But server wont accept that, it need `payload` for `POST` call. Also when comment those lines, it send direct `POST` call, no `OPTIONS` call before `POST`.

How to set the parameter that way, it will send cookies in each API call even for `OPTIONS` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

The point of the preflight OPTIONS request is to ask the server for permission before sending anything that could be used to do something dangerous.

If the credentials were included on it, then a naive server-side program which didn't check the HTTP method of the request could recognise a request to a given URL with acceptable credentials in it, and then perform an action.

This could be exploited by a malicious website.

---

Instead: You need to change the *server-side code* to exclude OPTIONS requests from any AuthN/AuthZ you perform.

Often this is just a case of registering middleware for handing CORS before any middleware for handling AuthN/AuthZ.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, do you know, why it not send `OPTIONS` when we not pass `payload` ?